How to express a solution set depending on subscripts?
I have encountered a large system of linear equations and found a solution but don't know how to write the solution set down.
Let's say for example that the there are solutions $x_{2i}=k_i$ and $x_{2i-1}=i$ with $k_i \in \mathbb{R},1\leq i\leq n$.
How would I write the solution set down?

The $x_j$ are the elements of your solution vector(s)?

@HackR Yes, they are

Is something like this acceptable :${x\in\mathbb R^{2n}\mid \pi_{2i}(x)=k_i,\ \pi_{2i-1}(x)=i,\ i\in[n]}$ where $\pi_j(x)$ is the projection of $x$ on the $j$-th coordinate?

@HackR I'm not sure. We haven't covered this yet. But I understand your point

If you want, you can define that function first, and then use it to write your set. Or you can just instead write (just like in the question) ${(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_{2n})\in\mathbb R^{2n}\mid x_{2i}=k_i,\ x_{2i-1}=i,\ i\in[n]}$.

@HackR Thank you! I think the last one is good.

As in the comments, we can write the solution set as $$\{(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_{2n})\in\mathbb R^{2n}\mid x_{2i}=k_i,\ x_{2i-1}=i,\ i\in[n]\}$$
